# python remove obect from array using condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries like below:

```
tt = [
{
     'property1': 'value1',
     'property2': 'value2',
     'property3': 'value3'
},
{
     'property1': 'value4',
     'property2': 'value5',
     'property3': 'value6'
},
..............................
.............................
]
```

How i can remove `'property3' : 'value6'` from above list of dictionaries?

To be precise, i need to remove all instances of key('property3') with specific value('value6') from all dictionaries in the list?

I am in need of fastest method, because list can be vary large.

Comment: why don't you tell us what you have already tried and what was not working?

Comment: This is not a website where people write code for you ... it is a website where people help you solving problems with your existing code

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Fairly straight forward so I won't explain it. Good Luck

```
def search(dict, key=None, val=None):
    c_dict = copy.deepcopy(dict)
    for i, n in enumerate(dict):
        for k, v in n.iteritems():
            if key and val and k == key and val == v:
                c_dict[i].pop(k)
            elif key and k == key:
                c_dict[i].pop(k)
            elif v and val == v:
                c_dict[i].pop(k)
            else:
                continue
    return c_dict

print search(d, 'property3', 'value6')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't notice that the poster only wanted to remove specific properties. Here's the correct solution:

```
tt=[{k:v for k,v in i.items() if k != 'property3' or v != 'value6'} for i in tt]
```

LazyScripter's solution will delete dictionary elements where the key OR the value OR both match.  If I understand the original question, I don't think this is what was desired.

I've also compared the efficiency of the two proposed solutions and the one-liner seems to be about 12X faster...

```
python -m cProfile test.py
```

outputs:

```
1780059 function calls (1500059 primitive calls) in 2.759 seconds

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    ...
        1    0.026    0.026    2.759    2.759 test.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.036    0.036    0.917    0.917 test.py:19(search)
        1    0.035    0.035    0.073    0.073 test.py:33(search2)
    ...
```

For the following code:

```
import copy

tt = [
{
     'property1': 'value1',
     'property2': 'value2',
     'property3': 'value3'
},
{
     'property1': 'value4',
     'property2': 'value5',
     'property3': 'value6'
}
]

d=[]
[d.extend(copy.deepcopy(tt)) for _ in range(10000)]

def search(dict, key=None, val=None):
    c_dict = copy.deepcopy(dict)
    for i, n in enumerate(dict):
        for k, v in n.iteritems():
            if key and val and k == key and val == v:
                c_dict[i].pop(k)
#            elif key and k == key:                                                                                                                                                                
#                c_dict[i].pop(k)                                                                                                                                                                  
#            elif v and val == v:                                                                                                                                                                  
#                c_dict[i].pop(k)                                                                                                                                                                  
            else:
                continue
    return c_dict


def search2(d,a,b):
    return [{k:v for k,v in i.items() if k != a or v != b} for i in d]

search (d, 'property3', 'value6')

search2(d, 'property3', 'value6')
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: Applying DeMorgan's theorem to "not (a and b)" gives "not(a) or not(b)".  The latter is more concise and may (or may not) be clearer.